# algolia and React - searchFunction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, react-native, algolia

can anyone helps me to find a solution
I am using React and I have to use Algolia for search events but I don't know how to handle the search event Algolia fire. When the search function fire I want to add something new to the page for example! Any help will be appreciated.

**[Documentation](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/instantsearch.html)**

I tried

```
const search = instantsearch({ 
  appId: myAppId, 
  apiKey: myAPIkey, 
  indexName: 'users', 
  searchFunction: () => {console.log('hi')} 
}: InstantSearchOptions);
```

but it doesn't work! And also I'm not sure if I imported the right module or no!

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution, if anyone struggle with this problem. The solution is CONNECTORS!
https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/guide/Connectors.html

Comment: Hi @Sara Mortada, in the end it seems that you switch librairies between InstantSearch.js and React InstantSearch. Do you mind sharing what connector you use and what kind of things you wanted to add to your page? Thanks!